# finite difference method with non-uniform mesh

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Can anyone suggest some good references for finite difference schemes to approximate $\frac{d^n y}{d x^n}, n = 1,2 \ldots,$ with non-uniform step size.  I need to know for domain with singularities or jump, how the grids are more finer at the singularity and away from the singularity the grids are coarser.

Comment: What have you found thus far?

Comment: I found this book: Interfacial Fluid Mechanics: A Mathematical Modeling Approach, chapter 2, section 4.5. But this has not much. And also observe from this book is that the order of convergence also decreases with non-uniform grids. Can you suggest some references, if possible, how to implement it.